# Avoiding duplicated messages on JMS/ActiveMQ

Tags: java, duplicates, jms, activemq-classic, mom

Is there a way to suppress duplicated messages on a queue defined on ActiveMQ server?

I tried to define manually JMSMessageID, (message.setJMSMessageID("uniqueid")), but server ignores this modification and deliver a message with built-in generated JMSMessageID.

By specification, I didn't found a reference about how to deduplicate messages.

In HornetQ, to deal with this problem, we need to declare the HQ specific property org.hornetq.core.message.impl.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID on message definition.

i.e.:

```
Message jmsMessage = session.createMessage();
String myUniqueID = "This is my unique id"; // Could use a UUID for this
message.setStringProperty(HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID.toString(), myUniqueID);
```

Somebody knows if there's a similar solution for ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at Apache Camel, it provides an Idempotent consumer component that would work with any JMS provider, see: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

Using that in combination with the ActiveMQ component makes using JMS quite simple, see:
http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Comment: I'm in doubt if this method will solve my problem. I need to keep just one instance of message with the same JMSMessageID just during this instance is in queue. I need it working as a Set. I want be able to put other message with the same JMSMessageID after the latest idem element was removed from queue. I need to implement it and test. But, based on Idempotent described on EAI book, I think that the concept doesn't matches with my necessity. BUt, the proposed solution is good. I will study more about it and comment here my results. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I doubt if ActiveMQ supports it natively, but it should be easy to implement an idempotent consumer. A way to do this would be to add a unique identifier to each message at the producer end, now at the consumer end using a store(db, cache etc), a check can be made to see if the message has been received before and continue to process based on that check.

I see a previous stackoverflow question along the same lines - [Apache ActiveMQ 5.3 - How to configure a queue to reject duplicate messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868349/apache-activemq-5-3-how-to-configure-a-queue-to-reject-duplicate-messages) , that may also help.

Comment: Since the consumer itself can be multi threaded, to identify whether its duplicate or not, one has to implement distributed/in-memory locking. Right?

Answer (score 4):

There is now support for removing duplicate messages baked into ActiveMQ transports. See the configuration values `auditDepth` and `auditMaximumProducerNumber` in the [Connection Configuration Guide](http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html).

Comment: how do you actually configure those parameters to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure what you're asking. How, in general, to apply configuration in ActiveMQ? Or what values to use for these specific fields?

Comment: It is just that from the description of the parameters it does not sound so clear to me. The `auditDepth` for example, does the value there means the Nb of messages or the nb of bytes that will be screened back for duplications? Regarding the `auditMaximumProducerNumber`, does that mean that there is a limited amount of producers that will be screened? Btw, if a message with the same content is published by 2 different subscribers, is the message by chance considered duplicated?

Comment: @Chris IIUC these parameters guarantee detection of duplicates for 2048 messages each on up to 64 producers. But how does ActiveMQ determine what is a duplicate? If it's by JMSMessageID then we're back to square one because we can't set that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to make ActiveMQ to filter duplicates based on a JMS property. it involves writing an Activemq [Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html). A basic broker filter that sends duplicate messages to the deadletter queue would be like this

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.Broker;
import org.apache.activemq.command.Message;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ProducerBrokerExchange;

public class DuplicateFilterBroker extends BrokerFilter {
    String messagePropertyName;
    boolean switchValue;

    public DuplicateFilterBroker(Broker next, String messagePropertyName) {
        super(next);
        this.messagePropertyName = messagePropertyName;
    }

    public boolean hasDuplicate(String propertyValue){
        switchValue = propertyValue;
        return switchValue;
    }

    public void send(ProducerBrokerExchange producerExchange, Message msg) throws Exception { 
        ActiveMQMessage amqmsg = (ActiveMQMessage)msg; 
        Object msgObj = msg.getMessage(); 
        if (msgObj instanceof javax.jms.Message) { 
            javax.jms.Message jmsMsg = (javax.jms.Message) msgObj; 
            if (!hasDuplicate(jmsMsg.getStringProperty(messagePropertyName))) {
                super.send(producerExchange, msg);
            }
            else {
               sendToDeadLetterQueue(producerExchange.getConnectionContext(), msg);
            } 
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: How this plugin decides which property will be used for further filtering of duplicate messages, explanation about use-case would be really helpful to integrate such plugin. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seem the way that is suggested in the question, works for ActiveMQ too (2016/12). See the [activemq-artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html)  guide. This requires the producer to set a specific property into the message.

```
Message jmsMessage = session.createMessage();
String myUniqueID = "This is my unique id";   // Could use a UUID for this
message.setStringProperty(HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID.toString(), myUniqueID);
```

However the class containing the property is different:
`org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.impl.HDR_DUPLICATE_DETECTION_ID` and the property value is `_AMQ_DUPL_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `jms.checkForDuplicates=true`?